# Mysql update on linux box hangs

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database on my Windows machine and another similar set up on Linux server.
While I had no issues in executing a very basic update/delete/drop query on Windows set up, my query hangs when run on Linux server.
MYSQL version on Windows machine is 5.1.42 while for Linux is 5.6.5-m8
Also, the hanging of update is not limited to a single table. There are 4-5 cross referencing tables in my datatabase for which this update/delete/drop is hanging.
Update/delete/drop is working for other un-related tables though.
On Linux, First, I simply source a dump(with no inserts) generated from my Windows machine. Second, I run an insert statement (`insert into flat (FLATID, BLOCKNO, FLATNO) Values (1, 'B1','F1');`). 
Third, I run update on the table(`UPDATE FLAT SET FLATNO='F2';`) and it hangs.
flat table description is below:

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FLATID               | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
||BLOCKNO              | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| FLATNO               | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
||col_COLID    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| famID_FAMID    | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| | allotID_ALLOTID | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
|+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: linux is case sensitive, have you tried UPDATE flat ...

Comment: I start mysql with --lower_case_table_names=1. Anyways, I attempted that too.doesn't work.I have tried restarting the Linux machine as well as well as installing MYSQL on other Linux machine as well but same issue.

Comment: you get some error message from server?

Comment: ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: seems like some query is locking that table or something. Try SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and see what happen.

Comment: It lists the same update query as the locked one. However, even when I close mysql and restart, the first update statement fails.

Comment: can you setup this in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and try there?

Answer (score 0):

After having tried almost everything including playing around with INNODB variables, i eventually tried removing reference allotID_ALLOTID from flat table. 
The ALLOTMENT table had reference to FAMILY table to which FLAT table had reference to as well.
Removing allotID_ALLOTID from both flat, family tables worked.